# Could not detect location using GPS in Android Studio

Tags: android, gps, android-location

I have tried following code to detect location using GPS. This code was working perfectly but suddenly when I checked the same code after a month it stopped working. I am getting something in the logcat but I couldn't get the meaning. Here is my code:

```
  private void currentlocation() {

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        onLocationChanged(location);
    } else {
        addressField.setText("Location not available");

    }
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    //You had this as int. It is advised to have Lat/Loing as double.
    lat = location.getLatitude();
    lng = location.getLongitude();

    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        List<Address> address = geoCoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);

        String addressStr = address.get(0).getSubLocality().concat(", ").concat(address.get(0).getLocality());

        builder.append(addressStr);
        builder.append(" ");

        String fnialAddress = builder.toString(); //This is the complete address.

        addressField.setText(fnialAddress); //This will display the final address.
        flagGotLocation=1;
        if(value.equals("Near By")) {
            near_by_restaurants();
        }
        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    } catch (IOException e) {
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    }
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {


}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

/**
 * methods for location ends here
 */
```

I have also added following permissions in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Post the logcat output

Comment: Add some details about where is it showing problem, logcat ouput and further code is welcome